# Programmatically Creating a Azure AD in C#

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to programmatically create a Azure Active Directory within a Azure subscription.

I have looked through the Azure Management API's and can see methods to create VM's, databases but not WAAD's.

If it is possible.  How many WAADs can be created per subscription?

Comment: AD tenants are usually tied to an account and not a specific subscription. Maybe you just need to add and manage users/applications/etc. within an existing one?

Comment: What i have done is create a multi-tenant application for Azure AD users ... it works well.   But what I want to do be is to be able to create a AAD for people who are not Azure subscribers themselves, then I would get all the AAD user management, security groups etc "For Free" and I wouldn't have implement a "bespoke" user management scheme within my application.

Comment: I must say though that I don't understand the restriction.  Within my own Azure Subscription I have 8 or so different AAD created for various testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to create Azure Active Directories programmatically.

As Jeff pointed, the directories listed in the Azure AD node are not contained in the subscription - but instead are the directories in which the currently signed in user account exists.