# Automating Active Directory Creation in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to azure and want to automate the process of AD creation. Could anyone suggest me the best way to do it??

Many suggested me to try it using azure-cli but I donot know it properly. Please suggest.

Comment: Based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002255/programmatically-creating-a-azure-ad-in-c-sharp, it is not possible to create an Azure AD programmatically.

Comment: Yaa...he is trying to use C#. But I am using a template to do it

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/active-directory-new-domain < there's a template for that

Comment: Michael, I have done that but I have an issue with that. Only Group Policy Management is being shown under roles. Rest of the roles are not being shown up. What do I do??

Answer (score 0):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718339/automating-the-deployment-of-azure-active-directory-using-command-line/39730911#39730911
```

This question answers this too.