# Automating the deployment of Azure Active Directory using Command Line

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have used the following command to achieve it :

```
azure group deployment create <my-resource-group> <my-deployment-name> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/active-directory-new-domain/azuredeploy.json
```

This link has a template which does it :

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/active-directory-new-domain/azuredeploy.json
```

I ran it several times but it shows this error :

```
info:    Resource 'adVM/CreateADForest' of type 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions' provisioning status is Running
info:    Resource 'adVM' of type 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'adNic' of type 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'adLoadBalancer' of type 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'csyh7daynrjiaadsa' of type 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'adPublicIP' of type 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'adAvailabiltySet' of type 'Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'VNet' of type 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments' provisioning status is Succeeded
info:    Resource 'adVNET' of type 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks' provisioning status is Succeeded

error:   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND management.azure.com management.azure.com:443
ApplicationInsights:Sender [ { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT dc.services.visualstudio.com:80]
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'dc.services.visualstudio.com',
host: 'dc.services.visualstudio.com',
port: 80 } ]
error:   Error information has been recorded to             C:\Users\admin\.azure\azure.err
error:   group deployment create command failed
```

The extensions part is failing. Could anyone tell what I have to do now???

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it....I was not in the **arm mode**.

```
azure config mode arm
```

And then type the commands posted above. This worked.